# Want to get printer data (toner, printed pages and etc) online

Tags: php, printing

i got printer added to computer via usb, later will add other printer directly to network.
So, i want to know, how i can get toner status, printed pages and other printer data online on a web.
I found this app http://www.papercut.com/products/ng/manual/ch-printer-mgmt-toner-levels.html, but i want to build own interface to display data on web. Basicly i just need collect printer data. My english so poor bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this data can be gathered using SNMP.  You need to get the MIB for the specific device.  In some cases you can get it using PJL.  No two manufactures will be the same in either case.  Basic items like page count and the name of the device may be found using he same SNMP MIB data/location but everything else will most likely be different.  Most manufacturers provide MIBs on their websites so you can 'walk the MIB' and gather the data you need.